# express router optional extensions

Tags: express, express-router

I have a route built up like this in different files.

I need one of the routes to respond to all of these extensions (including no extension):

```
/api/sitemap
/api/sitemap.xml
/api/sitemap.html
/api/sitemap.json
```

my unmounted route definition for the sitemap route looks like this:

```
router.route('/\.:ext?');
```

But the only path this one responds to is /api/sitemap. It does **not** accept any of the aforementioned extensions. In fact, it does not respond to any extensions at all.

Here's the buildup of my routes in condensed form:

```
/ 
/api
/api/sitemap (pattern should accept sitemap.xml sitemap.json or sitemap.html)
```

**root-routes.js**

```
const apiRoutes = require('./api-routes.js');
const router = require('express').Router();
const mainRoot = router.route('/');
mainRoot((req, res) => { res.status(200).send('ok') };
router.use('/api', apiRoutes); 
module.exports = router;
```

**api-routes.js**

```
const sitemapRoutes = require('./sitemap-routes.js');
const router = require('express').Router();
const apiRoot = router.route('/');
apiRoot((req, res) => { res.status(200).send('ok') };
router.use('/sitemap', sitemapRoutes);
module.exports = router;
```

**sitemap-routes.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const sitemapRoot = router.route('/\.:ext?');
sitemapRoot((req, res) => { res.status(200).send('ok') };
modules.exports = router;
```

Comment: do you need to capture and use the extension?

Comment: what happens if you use `router.use('/sitemap*', sitemapRoutes);` with the `*`

Comment: Yes, and I wish I wouldn't have to.

Comment: @terminally-chill The wildcard would only be a last resort. I need at least two more routes under sitemap. And maybe even more. And then it becomes messy.

Comment: I see what you mean. With the extension attached, it will not even enter the defined route. You can tell by using `router.use` as middleware within `sitemap-routes.js`. I think you might need to define a separate route in the `api-routes` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to match using another `.use` for the route using the extension.

```
apiRouter.use("/sitemap", sitemapRouter);

apiRouter.use("/sitemap.:ext?", (req, res) => {
    // sample response
    res.end(`${req.params.ext ? req.params.ext : 'root'} did match!`);
});
```

I tried a bunch of things, but could only get the desired route matches doing this. If you need to keep all `sitemap` related functions together, you should `export` the router and the function needed for the `/sitemap.:ext?` callback.

The other thing you can do is pass the `app` object in to the router, but this isn't desirable.

Comment: It's a kind of workaround. But still the closest thing to what I was hoping for.